# How to get Map on signed Android application?

Tags: android, dictionary

I have created a map application. It shows the map without signing the APK but while I try to sign and later install that APK in device the map does not display any more.

Comment: Hire a vocal coach ? but seriously what steps have you followed?, Your question is [vague](http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html)

Comment: Pretty sure you are the [same guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217139/how-to-get-map-on-signed-android-application) who wants to sing. Spamming the same question wont help.

Comment: If you could talk to your colleagues so you don't both ask the same question at the same time, that would be appreciated...

Answer (score 3):

You need a separate Google Maps API key for releasing. You say you are not signing the APK when it is working, but the application is actually being signed automatically by your SDK, using the debug key. This is probably the one for which you have a valid Google Maps API key as well.

From the documentation at https://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html:

> While you are developing and debugging
>   your application, you will likely be
>   sigining your application in debug
>   mode — that is, the SDK build tools
>   will automatically sign your
>   application using the debug
>   certificate. To let your MapView
>   elements properly display Maps data
>   during this period, you should obtain
>   a temporary Maps API Key registered to
>   the debug certificate. To do so, you
>   first need to get the MD5 fingerprint
>   of the debug certificate. When you are
>   ready to release your application, you
>   must register your release certificate
>   with the Google Maps service and
>   obtain a new Maps API Key. You must
>   then change the MapView elements in
>   your application to reference the new
>   API key.

Comment: If that is not the problem, I have come some other strange behaviour that might be relevant, described at http://www.kind-kristiansen.no/2010/android-map-tiles-not-loading-and-possible-fixes/

Comment: i have used this.beu even i am not able to get the map.

Comment: there does no error in logct bt we nt able to see the map...if we uses the unsigned apk then it does works properly...

Comment: If the map tiles are not loading, I bet there is some hint of why in the logs. Maybe you could post the relevant bits of the log to let people take a look. If you don't give any more info I doubt you'll get your question answered.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the same api key on two places? Cause the api key needs to be unique on each server.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html

Comment: Please create a new api key for the other server. You must not use same api key on each.

Answer (score 0):

You should generate another apiKey using the releasekey file which will be generate on signing.
You will get new MD5 key using the following
keytool -list -keystore c:\Users\Sudheesh\releasekey 
where relesekey is the file which contains the sign release key.
By using this MD5 key, you can generate the api key from  http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/android/android-mapview-generate-api-key-using-java-keytool/
Use this apikey in your app.

Answer (score 0):

its better to do in this way

```
Select the project in workspace-->rightclick---> click export--->export android apps-->next-->next--->enter keystore file name--->next--->enter key alis--->finish
```

(Please see this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308516/google-map-is-not-visible-in-my-android-app))

Answer (score 0):

Like what RogerKK said, how are you doing your tests/deployments?
If you initially Debugged the application against a connected Android device, that is most likely using a Debug Certificate SHA-1 generated key.  If you attempted to do a Release build, it requires a completely different key.

Here is what i ran through, but using a Debug certificate to sign.

http://www.digitalopium.com/android-google-maps-api-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

For all friends who are facing the same problem that nirav patel have.

You can use the following code to find the signed and unsigned hash key

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try

        {

            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("Your package name here",PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURE);

            for (Signature signature : info.signatures)
            {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } 
        catch (NameNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("name not found...."+e);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("NoSuchAlgorithmException...."+e);
        }
    }
}
```