# Google Map Problem

Tags: android, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get Map on signed android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217139/how-to-get-map-on-signed-android-application)

Dear Friend,

I have created one map application its show the map without signing the apk but while i m trying to sing and later, i install that apk in device at that time the map is not displaying
can you suggest me what i have to do for this problem ?

I used the Google Map api key also.