# google map is not visible in my android app

Tags: android, google-maps

in my app i am trying to show the current location in a map. I followed the instructions in his [link](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/android/android-mapview-generate-api-key-using-java-keytool/)

When i run the app from my eclipse to my device by the run config, I am able to view the map and the current place where i am located.

But when i created a .apk and aligned.apk file of my app then i am not able to see the map.

When i was searching through stack overflow i came over the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217139/how-to-get-map-on-signed-android-application)

and followed those answers but still i am not able to see the map, it shows only a squares
how to solve this issue

Comment: Do you use your map in debug mode or exported mode ? You should have different google map api keys for both.

Comment: What is mean by debug mode and exported mode.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its better to do in this way

```
Select the project in workspace-->rightclick---> click export--->export android apps-->next-->next--->enter keystore file name--->next--->enter key alis--->finish
```

Answer (score 0):

The only reason for this problem is with the keystore which you generate while exporting the apk... Select the already existing keystore androiddebug.keystore available in the android folder... Also remember that you should have valid api key with you..